# Put elements of an array to another by index values

Tags: c#, arrays, copy

I have two arrays where I compare the values and store the indexes to a List.
Now I want to go through another array, take the elements at the index places and copy them simply to a new array but I get an overFlowException. What to do?

```
for (int i = 0; i < _date.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < _date1.Length; j++)
    {
        if (_date[i] == _date1[j])
        {
            same_date = j;

            s_date.Add(same_date);
            overlap = s_date.ToArray();

        }
    }

for (int k = 0; k < overlap.Length; k++)
{
    _store[k] = _data[Convert.ToInt32(overlap[k])];
}
```

Comment: How many elements are we talking about here? Your cast to Int32 could overflow.

Comment: In which line do you get this exception?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: When I leave it out he tells me that he cant convert double to int. That are about 10 elements but that can vary. The array where I take the indexes of the overlapped values has about 900. I take about 10 indexes and want to copy values at these indexes from another array (has the same length - about 900) - He throws the exception in the last "for" loop

Comment: Why are you assigning `overlap` within the `if` statement? I think you'd do it ones, outside the loops?

Comment: no I assigned it at the very beginning but I just change the List to an array and store it there

Comment: which, of the 5 arrays is throwing the overflow?.. _store?

Comment: where is the closure for the first for loop?..

Comment: I dont know exactly - He just shows the line

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you save `j` (index of the `_date1` array) in the overlap variable, but you're using the overlap variable as index to the `_date` array.

This goes well, when the arrays are equal length.

---

update:

try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < _date.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < _date1.Length; j++)
    {
        if (_date[i] == _date1[j])
        {
            s_date.Add(j);
        }
    }
}

overlap = s_date.ToArray();

for (int k = 0; k < overlap.Length; k++)
{
    // use _data1 instead of _data  (k was an index of _data1 array)
    _store[k] = _date1[Convert.ToInt32(overlap[k])];
}
```

***Don't forget: _store much be the same size or larger than overlap.***

Haven't tested (yet)

Comment: what do you mean exactly? How should it be right? overlap is an array

Comment: Does not work. _date1 and _date are string arrays and _data is double. I check if dates are the same and then I need need the values from the _data array at the places were the dates were.

Comment: It has the same length like overlap (overlap.Length)

Comment: I think i need more context for this. I misread _data1 and _date1.   You should consider using more descriptive variable names..

Comment: sorry for that :/ Everything works fine but the last for loop and I dont understand why. Maybe it's the convert method?

Comment: remove `overlap` all together.. 
redimension `_store` to the length of `s_date.Count`.. `_store[k] = _date1[INDEX]`

Comment: make `INDEX` variable; and assign it as `Convert.ToInt32(s_date[k], 10)`.. and put a debug point on it.. I suspect your issue is that you're not getting an integer value from what would be the `overlap` array

Comment: actually.. nevermind that theory.. I see you're simply adding `J`, the iterator, to s_date in the first place .. (why are you doing a convert??)

Comment: opps... I somehow posted these comments on an answer.. sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

What if you try this approach:

```
string[] intersetedDates = _date.Intersect(_date1).ToArray();

int index = 0;
foreach (var currentDate in intersetedDates)
{
     _store[index] = _data[Array.IndexOf(_date1, currentDate)];
     index++;
}
```

The good thing about this code is that it eliminates loops and with the `Interset()` it will extract all of the values that are equal within the two arrays, just like you were looking for.

There is only one issue with this code though. Your date values have to all be unique because with the `IndexOf()` it will only match the first occurrence of a value. If you can ensure your values are unique, then I believe this would solve your overflow issue because there is no iteration except for `_store`.